# How to use fread to read 1st two bytes and next two bytes?

Tags: fread

I have a raw file with data in bytes

XX XX where each X represents 1 byte.

How do I read the 1st two bytes and the next two bytes separately ? I have only been able to read everything at one go. After reading the 2 bytes I would like to convert it to integer.

```
FILE * f = fopen(filename, type);

// Position pointer at 0
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

// Read file size
long lSize = ftell(f);

// Initialize temporary container
char *pixels;

// Allocate memory to temporary container
data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);

// Read intensity data
fread(data, 1, lSize, f);
```

Thanks.

XX XX X XXX....

Each X = 1 byte

1st two X represents number of rows
2nd two X represents number of cols

XXX onwards represents intensity data of image. I can read the image by moving fseek to position number 6 but I manually specified number of rows and columns because I do not know how to read the 1st two bytes and next 2 bytes **separately**

Comment: Declare or `malloc()` as many `unsigned shorts` as you have in your file and read the whole lot in one go.

Comment: First, do an `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` after the `ftell` to get back to the beginning of the file before reading. Second, check the return value of `fread` to verify that you are getting the expected number of bytes.

Comment: Sorry my skill is in OpenCV. I tried http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/ but I am not getting meaningful results. I need to be able to read in the 1st two bytes and concatenate them and get the integer representation of it

Comment: I tried the following but it says I am reading 0 bytes. Why would that be so ?

fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
 char buf[2];
 cout << fread(buf, 1, 2, f);

Comment: So, is the following statement true? You have a file where the values within it are just a load of 2-byte intensity values and you want to get the total length of the file in bytes and divide by two and end up with that many 2-byte integer values in a contiguous array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to do it without any sample data, but you will want something like this. You don't need to find the length of the file with `ftell()` by the way.

Untested code...

```
unsigned short nrows,ncols;

FILE * f = fopen(filename, type);

// Get number of rows
fread(&nrows,2,1,f);

// Get number of cols
fread(&ncols,2,1,f);

// Read all rows, one row at a time
for(r=0;r<nrows;r++){
    row[r]=(unsigned short*)malloc(ncols*2);
    fread(row[r],cols*2,1,f);
}
```

Comment: Wow it works. I struggle so much when the image input isnt in the standard jpg png etc format where i can use imread

Comment: Good - glad it got you started. You will probably need to `malloc()` an `(unsigned short**)` after the first 2 `fread()s` and before the `for` loop to accommodate your rows.